# is it possible to print lines followed if regex is matched?

Tags: bash

let say i have following data in a file:

```
name=Tom
    gender=male
    address=1st, 1st Ave.
    ...
```

or so.

so when i search this file, i am not only interested in whether Tom exists, but also all the info about Tom. so my question is is there any good tools to match a regex, then after that print the following n lines to stdout?

i wrote myself a perl script that does that but i hope there are simpler solutions since i work across multiple machines.

Comment: i do hate silent downvote in SO.

Comment: Question down votes are pretty straightforward: it shows a lack of research to answer the question yourself first. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes with `sed` and the following command

`sed [regex],+[#lines]!d file`

Then there is also grep

`grep -A [#lines] [regex] input_file`

which from the man page says

```
-A NUM, --after-context=NUM
Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines. Places a line containing a group separator (--) between contiguous groups of matches. With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.
```

Comment: i hope i can specify how many lines followed need to be printed.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr just did it with both grep and sed

Comment: well... the point is i don't have this option... you are using gnu grep right?

Comment: oh the first one makes sense.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr huh? and yes and `sed` you can also do it in `awk` as well but I didnt feel like posting that one.